# Sitecore Identity Server throws 431 error when the user have large number of assigned roles and groups

Tags: identity-server

I am using Sitecore 9.3 , i use the group claim that is received after authentication to map the users to specific roles and i have noticed that when the number of assigned roles and groups has increased it shows "HTTP ERROR 431" in the URL "/Account/ExternalLoginCallback".

when i checked the logs i found the below error:

```
    Connection id "" "" bad request data: ""Request headers too long.""
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Request headers too long.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException.Throw(RequestRejectionReason reason)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.TakeMessageHeaders(ReadOnlySequence`1 buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.ParseRequest(ReadOnlySequence`1 buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.TryParseRequest(ReadResult result, Boolean& endConnection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Any Advice?